# Assign query results to variables and select all variables in resultset

Tags: c#, mysql, t-sql, variables

I have five queries, each returning count for a specific criteria which is stored into local variables. I need all the variables into one resultset.

It looks working fine in MYSQL but getting exception when retrieving form c#

```
SET @Totalcount := (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Images WHERE ImageID > 9 AND name='abc') ;

SET @subTotal := (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Images WHERE ImageID< 100 AND name='xyz');

SELECT @Totalcount , @subTotal;
```

> Exception: ERROR [42000] [MySQL][ODBC 5.2(w)
>   Driver][mysqld-5.6.16-log]You have an error in your SQL syntax; check
>   the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near 'SET @subTotal := (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Images
>   WHERE ImageID=1 AND name' at line 2

What I am doing wrong?
I am new to mysql so not sure what is the problem.

Comment: Try to separate queries by semicolon.

Comment: `SELECT (SELECT COUNT(*) ...) AS totalcount, (SELECT COUNT(*) ... ) AS subtotal ...`

Comment: I had used in actual query but missed in the above post. I just updated the question to include the semicolons though it did not work for me.

Comment: no difference, same error

Comment: sorry, you was right. I just could not follow above syntax.